# Using SED to change heading names of a very large file

Tags: sed

I have a couple very large files that will not open up in any file editing program. I want to use sed to edit only the first line of headers to take the header and put a descriptor in front of it. My Files are a combination of pipe,comma and tab delimited.

Example:

```
Name City State Zip
```

will be ...

```
ExampleName ExampleCity ExampleState ExampleZip
```

Comment: What's your operating system?  If you can use perl, it can handle huge files.

Comment: (Please indicate, **in your question text**, what you consider a very large file, 4GB, or 10 TB are both very large files;-). But as you highlight that your files are too large to open in an editor, that is likely because there isn't enough tmp space to make a 2nd copy of the file. Did you check that? You won't be able to change that header in place (using normal Unix tool, as you'll always need space for the tmp copy. Once you have space, then you may need some other tricks to point your editor to that space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this if you mean the first line of the file:

```
sed -i '1 s/^.*$/NEW FIRST LINE/' yourfile
```

Or if the line you mean is not the first, but you only know it starts with "Name":

```
sed -i '/^Name/s^.*$/NEW HEADER LINE/' yourfile
```

**Added**

You can also do this sort of thing

```
echo Name City State | sed -E 's/([A-Za-z]+)/Example&/g'
```

Comment: It is always the first line. Is there a way to instead of typing out the whole first line just inserting the phrase "example" in front of each column name - so I'm guessing after each delimiter??

Comment: The problem is that my files are 250 columns long so don't want to continually do it. I edited your your first one so instead of "/^.*$/" it said "\t" but it only replaced it for the first header (not all ) .... Also realize with this way I will have to do it twice  1) search for tab replace with "\tExample" 2)Replace beggining of line with "Example"

Comment: Psych .... have to use /g to replace multiple lookups in a line! Final product [sed -i 1s/\t/\tExample/g file.txt]. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You are welcome - please consider accepting my answer (by clicking the hollow tick beside the vote count) if you are happy. If you are not, please say what's still wrong so I, and others, can assist you. Thanks.